# how to limit the size of a log file in tomcat catalina folder

Tags: java, tomcat

in my project,the log file is taking more memory compared to the assumed memory,so,my task is,i sholud make the tomcat server to generate new log file in catalina folder for every 2MB,it means log file size should limit for 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **-Dlog4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=5MB** in the log4j file to choose the size .
For more info http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html